# Using Lagrange multipliers to find max and min of a function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, 3d, lagrange-multiplier

The function is $f(x, y, z)=x^2+y^2-z$ subjected to $z=2x^2y^2+1$ .

My first step was to define $g(x, y, z)=z-2x^2y^2=1$

So $\nabla f = 2xi+2yj-k$, and $\lambda \nabla g = -4xy^2\lambda i -4x^2y\lambda j +\lambda k$

So I had the 3 equations

$$2x=-4xy^2$$
$$2y=-4x^2y$$
$$-1=\lambda$$

Substituting lambda we get

$2x=4xy^2$

$2y=4x^2y$

The solutions to this system of equations is $(0, 0)$ and $(\pm\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}, \pm\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2})$

Is this the correct way to do it? It makes me a little nervous that I don't have a $z$

Comment: You get the $z$ by plugging the $x$ and $y$ you found into the constraint $z = 2x^2y^2 +1$.

Comment: Are you forced to use Lagrange multipliers? If not, it is much simpler to substitute $z=2x^2y^2+1$ into $f$, to get an unconstrained function of two variables.